# Reading PWM Signal with MCU

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, embedded

I'm trying to read a PWM Signal.

I thought I could use a Voltage Divider and a ADC on MCU to "read" the PWM Input.

My PWM Signal is a 12V (13.8V Car Board Net) 100Hz Signal with a Duty of 90% or 10%

I attached the Voltage Divider.

If the Duty is on 90% the read value is mostly 4096 but flashes with 0 every few sec.
If the Duty is on 0% the read value is mostly 0 but flashes with 4096 every few sec.

For my project I just need to know if the Duty is on 10 or on 90% but with the flashes beween the readings I can't use it like now.

[image: VoltageDivider]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Sure: Why does the ADC is flashing 0 or 4096?

Comment: Because your sampling is not synchronized to your PWM waveform.

Comment: This should be done by measuring the time, not filtering to analog.

Comment: Indeed, use a digital timer pin, not the ADC. The ADC will be both crude and slow and adding an RC filter only means further inaccuracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to EE.SE!

Sounds like you are using an analog input on your MCU. If that's the case and you can live with some delay from a transition from 10 % to 90 % duty cycle, the easiest solution is a low pass filter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f03len.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can also solve this inside your MCU with some code to be able to tell if it's 10 or 90 % duty cycle being sent with no analog filtering.

Comment: Hi, the problem is, the Hardware is (as always:P) Ready. 

I can change the restistor Values of course. 

How can I do it inside the MCU? Why it doesnt work with the ADC Input?

Comment: You can solder C1 on top of R1. It does. You are seeing the interference pattern of the source PWM frequency and your ADC samplig. See here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106310/what-does-two-signals-aliasing-to-each-other-mean

Comment: Yes I can try that. You mean on top of R2, right? I use a 3.3V STM32 so I think the Resistor Values in your Draw are not correct,or?

Comment: Oh! I assumed 5 V MCU. Let me adjust. Yes, R2.

Comment: While this runs in the direction the asker started, it's not a very good solution to the actual *problem* compared to using the MCU's timer to measure the actual pulse timing.

Comment: Isn't this a counter related problem?  Why should I use ADC and this filter circuit for a 100 Hz signal.

Comment: @Chris and (at)Sadat I agree. It can be solved in software but a crude hardware fix may be simpler for OP to get started with.

Answer (score 3):

That is because a PWM signal is either fully on or fully off, but it in your case it will be fully on for 10% or 90% of the time. Depending on when the ADC samples it, it will be either fully on or fully off.

To read the analog signal, you need to lowpass filter it with a capacitor, but due to the frequency of 100Hz, you need to filter it with perhaps 10Hz filter.

Perhaps a better way would be to just measure the PWM pulse width (with a timer, or interrupt, or other method) to find length of each pulse.

Comment: Thanks. Which Value needs the Capacitor for a 10Hz Filter?

Comment: It depends on the resistor values you are going to use.